# Sendgrid on Google Compute Engine from port 465 or 587

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port, google-compute-engine, sendgrid

I'm working with a rails 4 app and am trying to send email via SendGrid. I have the app running from a GCE instance.

After reading [this google post](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) about sending email through sendgrid, I noticed that they only use port 2525. I would like to connect via port 465 (or 587) because after reading [this sendgrid post](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/smtp_ports.html) I learned that SendGrid only allows SSL connections via this port. It also recommends port 587 `to avoid any rate limiting that your server host may apply.`

Is there a way to use a port other than 2525 on a GCE instance?

```
Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465,
and 587 but you can still set up your instances to send mail through ports 587 
and 465 using servers provided through partner services, such as SendGrid.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, GCE only supports 2525.

TLS should work on port 2525. TLS is more frequently updated and has (so far) had fewer severe security incidents like POODLE, so TLS should be preferred.

GCE won't rate limit you on port 2525 in any particular way.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the thorough answer. A quick follow up: in your opinion, I shouldn't worry about not having SSL since TLS is just as secure?

Comment: Yep, TLS is essentially a newer version of SSL.